# django-filter no matches

Tags: django, django-filter

I couldn't find it in documentation so Im asking here. I've created filter with **django-filter** and it works properly, but if someone will select filters that none object has, then user will get empty page. I would like to add simple paragraph

None criteria matches

if filtered object don't exist.

I've tried with template tags like

{% if obj in filter.qs != none %}
{% endif %}

But it doesn't work. Does someone know how to make it?

filters.py

```
import django_filters
from .models import Company, COMPANY_TECHNOLOGIES
from django_filters import ChoiceFilter

class CompanyFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

class Meta:
    model = Company
    fields = ['type', 'city', 'students']

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(CompanyFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.filters['type'].extra.update(
        {'empty_label': 'All'})
    self.filters['city'].extra.update(
        {'empty_label': 'All'})
    self.filters['students'].extra.update(
        {'empty_label': 'All'})
```

comp_list.html

```
{% extends 'company/base.html' %}
{% block content %}

<div id="filter">
<form action="" method="get" id="submit">
    {{ filter.form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
{% for obj in filter.qs %}
<a href="/brands/{{obj.id}}">{{ obj.name }}</a>
    <p>Image {% if obj.image != None %}
    <img src="{{ obj.image.url }}">
    {% endif%}</p>
    <p>Icon {% if obj.icon != None %}
    <img src="{{ obj.icon.url }}" width="30" height="30">
    {% endif%}</p>

    <br> Type: {{  obj.type }} City: {{ obj.city }} Stack: {{  obj.stack }} 

{% if obj not in filter.qs %}
    <p>no matches</p>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
</div>
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Company
from .filters import CompanyFilter
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .serializers import CompanySerializer
# Create your views here.

def comp_list(request):
    f = CompanyFilter(request.GET, queryset=Company.objects.all())
    return render(request, 'company/comp_list.html', {'filter': f})

##def brands(request, slug):
##brands = Company.objects.all()
##return render(request, 'company/comp_view.html', {'brands': brands})

def brands(request, pk):
    brand = get_object_or_404(Company, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'company/comp_view.html', {'brand': brand})

#rest api


class CompanyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows groups to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = Company.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CompanySerializer
```

Comment: To which view are you sending the request? I can't see any in the form. It'd helpful if you could also post that view's code in here.

Comment: @LucaBezerra I'm sending it to comp_list, added views.py code

Comment: ```{% if obj in filter.qs %} {% endif %}``` should be enough? The **in** operator will return true if your *obj* is in the *filter.qs*, else false. If you want to check if it's not in there then negate it ```{% if obj not in filter.qs %} {% endif %}```

Comment: Idk what's wrong because It returns me only objects that matches the filter criteria, but if I add condition {% if obj not in filter.qs %} {% endif %} and inside it paragraph <p> None Matches </p> and then try to find some object that dont exist it doesnt return me this parapragh

Comment: @zypro negative condition doesnt work

Comment: @zypro I've solved this, all what I had to do is to add built in template tag {% empty %} but thanks anyway for your time guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for taking your time, I should go straight away to django docs and use built in template tag

```
{% empty %}
```

I've just added this into my comp_list.html like below

```
{% extends 'company/base.html' %}
{% block content %}

<div id="filter">
<form action="" method="get" id="submit">
    {{ filter.form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
{% for obj in filter.qs %}
{% if obj in filter.qs %}
<a href="/brands/{{obj.id}}">{{ obj.name }}</a>
    <p>Image {% if obj.image != None %}
    <img src="{{ obj.image.url }}">
    {% endif%}</p>
    <p>Icon {% if obj.icon != None %}
    <img src="{{ obj.icon.url }}" width="30" height="30">
    {% endif%}</p>

    <br> Type: {{  obj.type }} City: {{ obj.city }} Stack: {{  obj.stack }} 
{% endif %}
{% empty %}
    <p>no matches</p>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}</div>
```

And now everything works as it should, if user will try to filter object with criterias that dont match he will get response as paragraph `<p> No Matches </p>`